# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: selenium, android-emulator, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the below error when I am running my tests on my emulator.

```java
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
```

can someone help me in this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you close your browser without disposing your remotewebdriver, the selenium server will automatically clean up your session after an amount of time. If you are running your test when the selenium server cleans up your session, your current session may be disposed and cause this error.

Try running `remotedrive.Close()` every test, or just restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the browser in this way:
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();